# A question on making TitleBar

Tags: java, android

I want to make a title bar which has a image and text with `ImageView` and `TextView` respectively.I want text on image.I am adding and it is displaying but text and image separately.How can I make text on image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TextView and set background image to the textview to display text on image

**Example**

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textview2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:text="TextView" 
android:background="@drawable/top_color_bar"/>
```